# Connecting to MS SQL Database from Pentaho

Tags: sql-server, pentaho

I am trying to connect to sql server from Pentaho. I have created a user on the database and I am able to connect with that user from Pentaho. However, the user seems to require the sysadmin server role. Without that role, the user is unable to connect from Pentaho. The error message from Pentaho simply states that the login failed for user.

The user is able to login without the sysadmin role from the SSMS application.

Does a user seriously need to be a sysadmin to connect from Pentaho?

Answer (score 0):

No, user should not be sysadmin in order to connect to sql server from Pentaho. Create login first then map that login to user. Use the below commands.

```
create login login_name with password ='acds'
create user user_name for login login_name with default_schema='schema_name'
```